# Unable to input "*" in terminal for Java

Tags: java, string, terminal, console

I am trying to write a simple calculator in java that takes in an input in the console.

```
 eg. java 30 - 7  (works)
     java 30 * 7  (doesn't work)
```

After a little debugging, it seems that * is parsed into the main method as the class name instead of String '*'.

```
 eg. public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println(args[1]);
          // (returns Calculator.java and Calculator.class)
     }
```

Does anyone know why? And is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: You posted this exact question a few hours ago. Why are you posting it again?

Comment: @immibis Yeah i am on linux.

Comment: @Kon Sorry kon, I don't quite get you. It is probably someone else who posted that question you saw earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it seems that * is parsed into the main method as the class name instead of String '*'.

That's not what is happening.

The shell you're using (probably bash) expands `*` to match all files in the current directory, before `java` is called. This is known as [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) and has nothing to do with Java. If you don't want the argument to be parsed by the shell, pass a string:

```
java some_app '30 * 7'
```

Comment: Or escape it with `'*'` or `\*`. Using a string changes the number of arguments being passed.